# I added ImageButtons and listener, now emulator crashes

Tags: android

Here is my code below. When I just had the EditText Box code, it loaded fine. When I added the ImageButtons and listeners, it will not run at all. I do not want to add method code until I can get it to at least run. I am running on API 7

```
package org.chrome9.golfCalc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class launchCalculator extends Activity  {

       private EditText txtEditScore;
       private EditText txtEditRating;
       private EditText txtEditSlope;

       private ImageButton btnCalc;
       private ImageButton btnNext;
       private ImageButton btnBack;
       private ImageButton btnReset; 
       private ImageButton btnCourseHandicap;

       private TextView txtHeader;
       private TextView txtEnterScore;
       private TextView txtEnterRating;
       private TextView txtEnterSlope;
       private TextView txtBottom;


    // Variables in the application

    int[] Score = new int[20];
    double[] Rating = new double[20];
    double[] Slope = new double[20];

    double CourseHandicapResult = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnCalc = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
        btnCalc.setEnabled(false);
        btnCalc.setOnClickListener(calcListener);

        btnNext=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setEnabled(false);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(nextListener);

        btnBack=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        btnBack.setEnabled(false);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(backListener);

        btnReset=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
        btnReset.setEnabled(false);
        btnReset.setOnClickListener(resetListener);

        btnCourseHandicap=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCourseHandicap);
        btnCourseHandicap.setEnabled(false);
        btnCourseHandicap.setOnClickListener(courseHandicapListener);

        txtHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
        txtHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEnterScore);
        txtHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEnterRating);
        txtHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEnterSlope);
        txtHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtBottom);

        txtEditScore = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEditScore);
        txtEditScore.requestFocus();
        txtEditScore.setText("0");

        txtEditRating = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEditRating);
        txtEditRating.setText("0");

        txtEditSlope = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEditSlope);
        txtEditSlope.setText("0");

    }


    private OnClickListener calcListener=new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

        }
    };

    private OnClickListener nextListener=new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

        }
    };

    private OnClickListener backListener=new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

        }
    };

    private OnClickListener resetListener=new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

        }
    };

    private OnClickListener courseHandicapListener=new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

        }
    };

}
```

Main XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tblLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    /* Row 1: This is the Row for the header */
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/txtHeader" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_span="4" android:typeface="serif" android:textSize="18px"
            android:textColor="@color/darkblue" android:paddingBottom="15px"
            android:paddingTop="5px" android:text="      The Chrome9 Calculator v1.0" />
    </TableRow>

    /* Row 2: This is the Row for Entering the score */

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/txtEnterScore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0" android:layout_span="2" android:textSize="18px"
            android:textColor="@color/black" android:text=" Enter Your Score:     " />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/txtEditScore"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:numeric="integer"
            android:layout_column="2" android:layout_span="1" />
    </TableRow>

    /* Row 3: This is the Row for entering the Course rating */

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/txtEnterRating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0" android:layout_marginRight="30px"
            android:textSize="18px" android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text=" Enter Course Rating" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/txtEditRating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numeric="decimal" android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_span="1" />
    </TableRow>

    /* Row 4: The row for entering the course slope */

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/txtEnterSlope"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0" android:textSize="18px" android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text=" Enter Course Slope" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/txtEditSlope"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numeric="decimal" android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_span="1" />
    </TableRow>

    /* This separator view is used to separate
    the area below the buttons which will display the
    calculation results */
    <View android:layout_height="2px" android:background="#DDFFDD"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" />

    // Row 5 contains a text at column 2

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/txtHandicap" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18px"
            android:textColor="@color/black" android:text="Handicap:"
            android:layout_column="2" android:layout_span="1" />
    </TableRow>

    /* Row 6: Is the calcuation button and the textbox for the
    results of the handicap calculation*/

    <TableRow>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnCalc" android:src="@drawable/calculator32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/txtHandicap" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:numeric="decimal"
            android:layout_column="2" android:layout_span="1" />
    </TableRow>

    /* Row 7: Back button */
    <TableRow>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnBack" android:src="@drawable/back32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0" android:layout_span="1" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnCourseHandicap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2" android:text="Course" android:textSize="18px" />
    </TableRow>

    /* Row 8: The forward and reset/edit buttons */

    <TableRow>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnNext" android:src="@drawable/forward32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0" />
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnReset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2" android:src="@drawable/edit32" />
    </TableRow>

    /* Row 9: This is just a row for the plug of the company */

    <TableRow android:paddingBottom="10dip" android:paddingTop="5dip">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/txtBottom" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="0"
            android:textSize="14px" android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
            android:text="                         www.chrome9.org" />
    </TableRow>

    // End of all rows and widgets

</TableLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.chrome9.golfCalc"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:name=".launchCalculator"
                  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Eyes are not good at compiling and executing code... why don't you paste the `logcat` once the app has crashed?

Comment: Two things. 1) You can't use C/C++ style comments in XML files. 2) What is the stack trace?

Comment: As @Qberticus says the comments in the XML will ruin the parser, is this for illustration for your question purposes only or are those really in your file in place of XML style comments `<!--` / `-->` ?

Comment: I took the comments out. I forgot about them. It still crashes as soon as the emulator starts up. Here is the logcat message:

[2010-07-03 19:52:38 - Logcat]device (emulator-5554) request rejected: device not found
java.io.IOException: device (emulator-5554) request rejected: device not found
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(Unknown Source)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(Unknown Source)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Unknown Source)
 at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogPanel$3.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: You can make the example as small as possible. One ImageButton is enough to reproduce if it will crash again.

Comment: Is it possibly a permissions issue? If so, which one? I will list the entire logcat errors if that will help. I want to thank you guys for your help. It is very frustrating and I know it is something simple I am missing.

Comment: 07-08 02:00:43.102: ERROR/System(61): java.lang.SecurityException
07-08 02:00:43.102: ERROR/System(61):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
07-08 02:00:43.102: ERROR/System(61):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
07-08 02:00:43.102: ERROR/System(61):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
07-08 02:00:43.102: ERROR/System(61):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:176)

Comment: I found the problem. I had placed <Button> instead of <ImageButton> in one spot in my main.xml. Thank you for all of your help. I learned a lot about debugging.